# ipad: how to know editing done in UITextView?

Tags: ipad

I've a textview. I want to know whether the changes done in textview while pressing back button in UINavigationBackbutton. how to compare old and new text entered in UItextview?
If there is any changes, i'll ask Do u want to save the changes?.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a flag when your UITextView did begin editing (wasEdited=YES) and save the current state of the text (originalText = myTextView.text) then on backbutton check the (originalText isEqualToString:myTextView.text && wasEdited)

The was edited tag is to avoid string comparaison in case the user didn't get into editing :)

Answer (score 0):

iphony,

Better late than never...

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewShouldBeginEditing");
 return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing");
}
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewDidChange");
}
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewDidChangeSelection");
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewShouldEndEditing");
 return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
 NSLog(@"textViewDidEndEditing");
}
```